# $apply with two operations, where one depends on the other

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my angular directive, in a callback, I call `$apply` to:

1. Set `$scope.model.something`
2. Invoke `$scope.onAction()` which uses `model.something`.

I do this in one `$apply` call, but at the time `onAction()` is invoked, `model.something` is still undefined.

At the same time, after $apply, `{{model.something}}` has a correct value, so model.something is updated correctly.

I want `model.something` to be set, so I can use it in `onAction()`. How to fix the following code?

Here's the directive (I skipped not relevant code):

```
.directive(function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      onAction: '='
    },
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
      return function (scope) {
        // This is some callback which is invoked
        // outside of digest cycle.
        function callback() {
          // Here I want to set model and call onAction callback
          scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.ngModel = 'something';
            scope.onAction();
          });
        }
      }
    }
  };
})
```

At the same time, my controller looks like:

```
var MyController = function ($scope) {
  $scope.model = {};

  $scope.onAction = function () {
    // Here I want $scope.model.something to be set to "something"
    // But it's undefined.
    alert($scope.model.something);
  };
}
```

Finally, HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  {{ model.something }}
  <my-directive ng-model="model.something" on-action="onAction"/>
</div>
```

One more thing, I know I could just call `scope.onAction('something')`, I'm looking for some other solution.

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hF362/).

Comment: I dont think you have linked to the relevant fiddle.

Comment: @CodeHater - right, thanks - now the link is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply wrap each line into it's own $apply callback:

```js
compile: function (element, attrs, transclude) {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      var something = 'lorem ipsum';
      scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.ngModel = something;
      });
      scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.onAction();
      });
    }, 200);
  };
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87EQh/)

Comment: Proper way is to use ngModelController to communicate with the ngModel directive, and to use $watch to observe changes on the model: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ar8D/).

Answer (score 1):

Use `$timeout`:

```
$timeout(function(){
    scope.onAction(something);
});
```

Or use `$watch`:

```
scope.$watch("ngModel",function(){
    scope.onAction(something);
});
```